# how to use HTML5 tags properly?

Tags: html

Being very new in web designing I was wandering, how should i properly use HTML5 tags. Taking an particular example. I want to put some content in the middle of the page. So in HTML4 I write.

```
<div class="content-container">
      <div class="left-content"></div>
      <div class="right-content"></div>
</div>
```

but to use HTML5 properly should I write the same code as .

```
<div class="content-container">
          <article class="left-content"></article>
          <aside class="right-content"></aside>
</div>
```

I am really confused about properly using the tags. Pardon me if that was a dumb question. cheers!

Comment: It is impossible to say what elements best describe the semantics of your content without knowing what your content is. (You do need to have end tags that match their associated start tag though).

Comment: The use HTML4 tags is not semantic: you use <div> to divide the screen in different parts. HTML5 is semantic, so just think what you really wanna mean (which kind of content you will put there), choose the tag you think that fits better and don't worry about 'proper use'

Comment: you need to you latest doctype for html5  <!DOCTYPE html>  and  for more  you study  from online tutorial  like for the input    type  mail and type password etc any thing which help you lot

Comment: Your site won't blow up for _improper_ use of HTML5 tags. Don't sweat the small stuff, it will come later on. But if you _do_, make sure you use a [shiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv) so you have backwards support for IE 8 and below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is understanding the HTML5 semantics elements. Here is a quick and easy-understood explanation for you from [HTML5 doctor](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/)
[image: HTML5 element flowchart]

However, you can search with the keyword "**HTML5 semantic**" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax: Dont close the tags with

```
</div>
```

It should be:

```
<article class="left-content"></article>
<aside class="right-content"></aside>
```

These tags are used to tell what kind of content is inside them, for example if a screen reader reads your html, it can tell what it should read and what not through these tags.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is partly the support of screen readers. If you have a sight disability (e.g. are blind) and have to rely on screen readers to read the content aloud, this helps the screen reader to discern between actual content and, say ads or footers.

Comment: While technically only slightly wrong, I'd rather mention SEO. A robot encountering `article`s and `aside`s has a much better chance of understanding and properly rating a page than with a bunch of unsemantic `div`s.

Answer (score -1):

It's really easy: When you open a tag you have to close it.

```
<div class="content-container">
      <article class="left-content"></article>
      <aside class="right-content"></aside>
</div>
```

There are some [void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element) which don't allow to have contents and don't need a closing tag:

```
area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen,
link, meta, param, source, track, wbr
```

Example:

```
<br>
<meta name="description" content="This is a meta tag">
```

A full list of all HTML5 elements and their meaning you'll find [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/elements.html#html-elements).